# With a UK 6-months visa, can I leave and re-enter before that?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

I am Argentine, was travelling through Europe for three months and obtained a visa to come to UK for six months:

NWT 26164
Leave to enter for/until 6 months.
No work or recourse to public funds.
Immigration officer (6038)
13  sep. 2015

And he said I could not leave and apply for six more months soon. Three months have gone by and I want to go to Germany for one month.

Will I be able to come back into the UK?

My remaining time in UK will be the three months left of my visa?

So they gave me six months within how long, 12 months?

Comment: Is your visa multiple entry?

Comment: @DJClayworth it looks to me like the OP has no visa, and is using the word "visa" to refer to the entry stamp in her passport.

Comment: No, your existing LTE will be spent once you exit the CTA. You can always try to get a new one by presenting yourself at a port,

Comment: @GayotFow I think the question is, in light of the statement that OP cannot "apply for six more months soon," and in light of the fact that, as you say, her current LTE is spent once she leaves the UK, what is likely to happen if she goes to Germany for a month and then seeks to return to the UK for two or three months?

Comment: I see...  It's within the rules, but the OP needs to clear a more probing landing interview.